# Android DB Update near "WHERE": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I know there are already too many questions about this, and believe me I've done my part reading the answers to find a solution. Unfortunately, I can't find my mistake

Here's my code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("eat_it", 1);
values.put("expired", 1);
String[] args = {food.name, "0"};

db.update("foods", values, "name=? AND expired=?", args);
db.close();
```

What I want to do:

Find a record in the table `foods` `WHERE` the value of column `name` = `food.name` and the value of column `expired` = `0`. If found, `SET` the record's `eat_it` column to `1` and `expired` column to `1`. If no record found, don't do anything

Here's my create table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foods (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    ...
    eat_it INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    expired INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);
```

Here's the error message:

```
...
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE foods SET expired=?,eat_it=? WHERE name ='Taco Salad'WHERE expired = 0
...
```

Thanks for your help

====UPDATE====

Apparently after I restart my computer it worked. I think my emulator was not working properly/ still has the old code. Thanks everyone for helping

Comment: it looks like this is not the code that caused this exception

Comment: @njzk2 you're right. I'm so sorry, I should've restarted my computer before asking it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message returned per your post

> near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE foods
>   SET expired=?,eat_it=? WHERE name ='Taco Salad'WHERE expired = 0

It's clear from the error statement that you have two `WHERE` clause in your query and so the error.

```
UPDATE foods SET expired=?,eat_it=? 
WHERE name ='Taco Salad'
WHERE expired = 0 <-- Here
```

Your `UPDATE` statement should look like

```
UPDATE foods SET expired=?,eat_it=? 
WHERE name ='Taco Salad'
AND expired = 0
```

Comment: I figured that too. But my third argument is : `"name=? AND expired=?"`. I don't know why but the `AND` is not showing in the error message

Answer (score 0):

You can use the where statement without using the 'whereArgs' like this:

`db.update("foods", values, "name="+food.name+" AND expired=0", null);`

Also, since you're updating internal values, you can also try a simple query:

`db.rawquery("UPDATE foods SET eat_it=1, expired=1 WHERE name="+food.name+" AND expired=0");`

Although there should be nothing wrong with what you wrote there, you can try those two options to make it work.

Comment: why would you do that? why would you suggest to not use the tools at our disposal? and more to the point, why would you think it would work any better? (fyi, your queries obviously fail because food.name is a string)

Comment: Because it's obviously not working properly, right? Besides, if he can't make it work even with a raw query, then he knows problem is not in the statement, but in the vars.
Hum, yeah? food.name is a string. Functions expects string... what's the problem?

Comment: exactly. it's not working properly, yet nothing seems wrong, and looking at the error tells us that the code is not related to the error. There is no point in fiddling around trying different methods of obtaining the same result if what the error is is not clear in the first place

Comment: Alright, you have a point there. But I still think that trying other methods of getting the same result, and getting the same exception in return **does help** to find that the problem was with the compiler/emulator